# Deadlock on the same resource calling the same procedure

Tags: sql-server, locking, transaction, deadlock, concurrency

I would like to kindly ask community for help with this deadlock scenario:
[image: Deadlock graph]

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process17392264e8">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process17392264e8" taskpriority="5" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 7:2018106230:0 " waittime="4449" ownerId="394509589" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-06-05T12:06:41.320" XDES="0x18ed9516f0" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="4" kpid="8348" status="suspended" spid="143" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="-5" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2019-06-05T12:06:41.310" lastbatchcompleted="2019-06-05T12:06:41.310" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.310" clientapp="Helios Orange" hostname="???" hostpid="508" loginname="???" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="394509589" currentdb="7" currentdbname="XXXXXX" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673384544" clientoption2="128568">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="XXXXXX.dbo.hp_ZdvojeniKonstrukceATech" line="73" stmtstart="6876" stmtend="7250" sqlhandle="0x03000700efbf9d27f8924d01e9a8000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE CZ SET IntPermanentniZmena=0 
         FROM TabDavka D 
           INNER JOIN TabCZmeny CZ ON (CZ.ID=D.ZmenaOd AND CZ.IntPermanentniZmena=1) 
         WHERE D.IDDilce=@IDKusovni     </frame>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="44" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x010007000f5ba906f09b4b6f0700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC @ret=hp_ZdvojeniKonstrukceATech 120234, 39008, 1     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
DECLARE @ret integer
EXEC @ret=hp_ZdvojeniKonstrukceATech 120234, 39008, 1
SELECT @ret    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process15bf6ce8c8" taskpriority="5" logused="0" waitresource="OBJECT: 7:2018106230:0 " waittime="6020" ownerId="394493191" transactionname="user_transaction" lasttranstarted="2019-06-05T12:06:39.750" XDES="0x16fb190ea0" lockMode="IX" schedulerid="1" kpid="3940" status="suspended" spid="83" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="-5" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2019-06-05T12:06:39.750" lastbatchcompleted="2019-06-05T12:06:39.750" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.750" clientapp="Helios Orange" hostname="???" hostpid="14924" loginname="???" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="394493191" currentdb="7" currentdbname="XXXXXX" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="673384544" clientoption2="128568">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="XXXXXX.dbo.hp_ZdvojeniKonstrukceATech" line="73" stmtstart="6876" stmtend="7250" sqlhandle="0x03000700efbf9d27f8924d01e9a8000001000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
UPDATE CZ SET IntPermanentniZmena=0 
         FROM TabDavka D 
           INNER JOIN TabCZmeny CZ ON (CZ.ID=D.ZmenaOd AND CZ.IntPermanentniZmena=1) 
         WHERE D.IDDilce=@IDKusovni     </frame>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="2" stmtstart="44" stmtend="152" sqlhandle="0x0100070009fde604c031f1451a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
EXEC @ret=hp_ZdvojeniKonstrukceATech 120073, 39047, 1     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
DECLARE @ret integer
EXEC @ret=hp_ZdvojeniKonstrukceATech 120073, 39047, 1
SELECT @ret    </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="2018106230" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="XXXXXX.dbo.TabCzmeny" id="lock134d414780" mode="S" associatedObjectId="2018106230">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process15bf6ce8c8" mode="S"/>
     <owner id="process15bf6ce8c8" mode="IX" requestType="convert"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process17392264e8" mode="IX" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
   <objectlock lockPartition="0" objid="2018106230" subresource="FULL" dbid="7" objectname="XXXXXX.dbo.TabCzmeny" id="lock134d414780" mode="S" associatedObjectId="2018106230">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process17392264e8" mode="S"/>
     <owner id="process17392264e8" mode="IX" requestType="convert"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process15bf6ce8c8" mode="IX" requestType="convert"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </objectlock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

It's on the same resource (table) and is being caused by the same procedure invoked from two sessions.

Simplified flow of the procedure is like that:

```
SELECT @Variable = Column FROM Table WITH (HOLDLOCK)
…
UPDATE Table SET...
```

I would greatly appreciate any advice how to prevent this deadlock scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `HOLDLOCK` is creating the "Shared" lock (the `Mode: S` locks) on that resource for the duration of the transaction. This does not prevent other processes (such as the same proc executed in another session) from placing their own "Shared" lock on the same resource. But then both sessions get to the `UPDATE` statement which is trying to convert (i.e. upgrade) their lock to "Intent eXclusive" (the `Mode: IX` locks), which can't be done due to the other session still holding its "Shared" lock.

If the purpose of the `HOLDLOCK` is to reserve the row for that session (so that others cannot modify it), then you need to prevent other sessions from being able to place their own "Shared" lock on that same resource (at the same time, of course).

One way to do this is by changing the `HOLDLOCK` to `UPDLOCK` (i.e. "Update" lock). This allows other transactions to take the same lock on the same resource (like `HOLDLOCK`), but one of those transactions can convert/upgrade to an `XLOCK` which will then force all other transactions (still with their `UPDLOCK`) to wait until the transaction is over (unlike `HOLDLOCK`). Also, while the lock is still an "Update" lock (i.e. prior to converting to an "eXclusive" lock), other transactions/sessions can read that resource  (also like `HOLDLOCK`).

If there is at least one row to update and the lock converts to an "eXclusive" lock, and you have other processes that need to access this table without waiting around for all of these updates to complete, then you have a few choices:

1. use `WITH (NOLOCK)` hint (read modified but not yet committed so might roll-back row)
2. use `WITH (READPAST)` hint (skip row entirely as if it doesn't exist)
3. look into `SNAPSHOT ISOLATION` (read current / unmodified row)

The following test should illustrate all of this:

**Query Tab A**

Paste the following into one query tab in SSMS (i.e. session) and execute only the statements within the block quote (for now; i.e. the `USE`, `CREATE TABLE`, and `INSERT`)

```
USE [tempdb];

/*
-- DROP TABLE dbo.test;

USE [tempdb];
CREATE TABLE dbo.test
(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1, 1) PRIMARY KEY,
  [col1] INT NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO dbo.test ([col1]) VALUES (11), (13), (15);
*/

DECLARE @ID INT;

BEGIN TRAN;

SELECT @ID = [ID] FROM dbo.test WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK) WHERE [col1] = 13;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.000';

UPDATE dbo.test SET [col1] = 88 WHERE [ID] = @ID;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:5.000';

ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

**Query Tab B**

Paste the following into another query tab in SSMS (i.e. another session) but do not execute it (yet).

```
USE [tempdb];

DECLARE @ID INT;

BEGIN TRAN;

SELECT @ID = [ID] FROM dbo.test WITH (ROWLOCK, UPDLOCK) WHERE [col1] = 15;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.000';

UPDATE dbo.test SET [col1] = 999 WHERE [ID] = @ID;
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:5.000';

ROLLBACK TRAN;
```

**Query Tab C**

Paste the following into another query tab in SSMS (i.e. another session) but do not execute it (yet).

```
USE [tempdb];

SELECT * FROM sys.dm_tran_locks --WHERE [request_session_id] IN (x, y);

SELECT 'readpast', * FROM dbo.test WITH (READPAST);

SELECT 'nolock', * FROM dbo.test WITH (NOLOCK);
GO -- separate next query as it will lock up once an UPDATE statement starts

SELECT 'no hint', * FROM dbo.test
```

**Main Test**

1. Go to "Query Tab A", hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.
2. Wait a second or two, then go to "Query Tab B", hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.
3. Go to "Query Tab C", hit <kbd>F5</kbd>.

   1. You should see 6 or so rows for the first query (i.e. `sys.dm_tran_locks`). If you have a bunch of stuff going on in the system, uncomment the `WHERE` clause and replace `x` and `y` with the session IDs (i.e. SPIDs) for "Query Tab A" and "Query Tab B".
   2. You should also get 3 rows back for each of the 3 `SELECT ... FROM dbo.test ...` queries. So far only "Update" locks have been taken.
   3. Wait a second or two and hit <kbd>F5</kbd> again. Do this a few times until the final query doesn't come back right away.
   4. Once "Query Tab A" gets to the `UPDATE` statement, for a few seconds:

      1. you will only get 2 rows back from the first `SELECT ... FROM dbo.test ...` query (i.e. `READPAST`)
      2. you will get all 3 rows back from the next query (i.e. `NOLOCK`), but row #3 will show the uncommitted value.
      3. the final query will not come back at all (i.e. no hints) as it is now blocked by the "eXclusive" lock (this is why the `GO` exists, just prior to this query, so that the others can return their result sets while this one gets blocked)